# Efecto "Pulso" en CSS3

Tags: css, css3, css-transform

***Hola, estoy intentado lograr un efecto de "Pulso" sobre un circulo, usando solo CSS3 puro. Abajo dejo un ejemplo de lo esperado.*
Es posible?**

**Esperado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actual**

```css
#circle {
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 background: green ;
 -moz-border-radius: 50px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
 border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#icono{
  width: 42px;
 height: 42px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 14.5px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="circle" class="button">
 <img id="icono" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/10685-200.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lo puedes conseguir creando pseudo-elemtos `:before` y `:after` y aplicándoles la misma animación con un retraso para dar ese efecto. La idea sería que tuvieran un borde que cambie de color y tamaño.

Algo como esto:

```css
.circle {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: green;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle::before, .circle::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  border-radius:100%;
  animation: latido linear 3s infinite;
}

.circle::after {
  animation-delay: -1.5s;
}

@keyframes latido {
  0% { width:70px; height:70px; border:10px solid gray; }
  100% { width:120px; height:120px; border:10px solid transparent; }
}

.icono {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 14.5px;
}

#button-0 { top: 50px; left: 100px; }
```

```html
<div class="circle button" id="button-0">
  <img class="icono" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/10685-200.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow.............

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, muchisimas gracias.